# Adding a custom field type to SugarCRM?

Tags: module, field, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm trying to add a custom field type to our SugarCRM 6.2 instance. I want to add an "`email link`" type field. I want it to function like the URL field, but prefix every address with `"mailto://"` prefix instead of `"http://"`.

It will be good if that field type is available in studio while creating new fields or in minimum, some custom code to achieve it.

What I did up to now:
- I've copied include/SugarFields/Fields/URL to include/SugarFields/Fields/Email
- In modules/ModuleBuilder/language/en_us.lang.php I've added a title for the email field

But unable to get anything working. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

First of all you do not want to make any coding changes outside of the custom directory. Doing so outside of this directory is not upgrade safe.

1. Create a custom fields directory in your custom folder
2. Create new template files (.tpl) for your custom field

then you can just add a regular textfield in studio
then edit your viewdefs in your custom directory
in your tpl file concatenate the mailto:// to your text and just add the persons email address and it will take care of the rest for you

Answer (score 0):

why you need custom field type for such small functionality? Just add your custom JS file in `editviewdef.php`. Then use some `jQuery selector` to perform certain action. For detail view, you can use `view.detail.php` to add required text in run time.

This will help you to store less data in database and display more in frontend.